Stable-Baselines3 DQN with Gym Four Rooms Minigrid: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`
I'm encountering a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable error when trying to create a DQN model with Stable-Baselines3 (SB3) and the Gym Four Rooms Minigrid environment.
import gymnasium as gym
import minigrid
from stable_baselines3 import DQN

env = gym.make("MiniGrid-FourRooms-v0")
model = DQN("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1)

At which point I get the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-8325428a1aca> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 from stable_baselines3 import DQN
----> 2 model = DQN("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/stable_baselines3/dqn/dqn.py in __init__(self, policy, env, learning_rate, buffer_size, learning_starts, batch_size, tau, gamma, train_freq, gradient_steps, optimize_memory_usage, target_update_interval, exploration_fraction, exploration_initial_eps, exploration_final_eps, max_grad_norm, tensorboard_log, create_eval_env, policy_kwargs, verbose, seed, device, _init_setup_model)
     83     ):
     84 
---> 85         super(DQN, self).__init__(
     86             policy,
     87             env,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/stable_baselines3/common/off_policy_algorithm.py in __init__(self, policy, env, policy_base, learning_rate, buffer_size, learning_starts, batch_size, tau, gamma, train_freq, gradient_steps, action_noise, optimize_memory_usage, policy_kwargs, tensorboard_log, verbose, device, support_multi_env, create_eval_env, monitor_wrapper, seed, use_sde, sde_sample_freq, use_sde_at_warmup, sde_support, remove_time_limit_termination, supported_action_spaces)
    102     ):
    103 
--> 104         super(OffPolicyAlgorithm, self).__init__(
    105             policy=policy,
    106             env=env,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/stable_baselines3/common/base_class.py in __init__(self, policy, env, policy_base, learning_rate, policy_kwargs, tensorboard_log, verbose, device, support_multi_env, create_eval_env, monitor_wrapper, seed, use_sde, sde_sample_freq, supported_action_spaces)
    154 
    155             env = maybe_make_env(env, self.verbose)
--> 156             env = self._wrap_env(env, self.verbose, monitor_wrapper)
    157 
    158             self.observation_space = env.observation_space

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/stable_baselines3/common/base_class.py in _wrap_env(env, verbose, monitor_wrapper)
    194             if verbose >= 1:
    195                 print("Wrapping the env in a DummyVecEnv.")
--> 196             env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])
    197 
    198         if (

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/stable_baselines3/common/vec_env/dummy_vec_env.py in __init__(self, env_fns)
     29         self.keys, shapes, dtypes = obs_space_info(obs_space)
     30 
---> 31         self.buf_obs = OrderedDict([(k, np.zeros((self.num_envs,) + tuple(shapes[k]), dtype=dtypes[k])) for k in self.keys])
     32         self.buf_dones = np.zeros((self.num_envs,), dtype=bool)
     33         self.buf_rews = np.zeros((self.num_envs,), dtype=np.float32)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/stable_baselines3/common/vec_env/dummy_vec_env.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     29         self.keys, shapes, dtypes = obs_space_info(obs_space)
     30 
---> 31         self.buf_obs = OrderedDict([(k, np.zeros((self.num_envs,) + tuple(shapes[k]), dtype=dtypes[k])) for k in self.keys])
     32         self.buf_dones = np.zeros((self.num_envs,), dtype=bool)
     33         self.buf_rews = np.zeros((self.num_envs,), dtype=np.float32)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I have looked for many solutions, and I don't to reimplement DQN from scratch.
I tried to use stablebaselines3 and gymnasium to run DQN on minigrid fourrooms.

See this GitHub issue. I think you are suffering the exact same problem with this comment. The key point is the structure of the observation space of MiniGrid. Compare it with, for example, CartPole environment, which outputs no error inside your code.
